# How to terminate a generator without try / except and raise StopIteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, iterator, generator

I am trying to terminate the iteration of a generator function I created without the program terminating as soon as `StopIteration` is encountered. I know I can use a `try` / `except` statement to catch the thrown exception, but is there a way to terminate the generator function without an exception being thrown?

My code:

```
def isPalindrome(num):
    if num == int(str(num)[::-1]):
        return True
    return False

def palindrome_special():
    num = 0
    while True:
        if isPalindrome(num):
            yield num
            if len(str(num)) == 10:
                raise StopIteration
            num = 10 ** len(str(num)) #If palindrome is encountered, a reassignment takes place to calculate the next palindrome containing 1 more digit
        num = num + 1

for i in palindrome_special():
    print(i)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, because you don't terminate a generator. It doesn't do anything except respond to your request for another element via a call to `next`. If you don't make that call, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Further, the exception is how `next` differentiates between an actual value being produced by the generator, and the generator having nothing left to produce.

Comment: Also there's absolutely nothing wrong with exceptions being thrown, as long as you catch and handle them appropriately. In fact, it is very pythonic to [ask for forgiveness instead of permission](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Comment: What do you have against exceptions?

Comment: The correct way for a generator to end is just to exit the function. In fact, an unhandled `StopIteration` inside a generator is treated as a `RuntimeError` in Python (since version 3.5). If something inside a generator raises StopIteration you are supposed to handle it, e.g. by exiting with `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generator does not need to be terminated. It will simply stop yielding values when we make it stop yielding values. Rewriting the code with an if statement and a break in the generator function will do that.

```
    def isPalindrome(num):
        if num == int(str(num)[::-1]):
            return True
        return False
    
    def palindrome_special():
        num = 0
        while True:
            if isPalindrome(num):
                if len(str(num)) <= 10: #If statement
                    yield num
                else: #condition that terminates the generation of values
                    break
                num = 10 ** len(str(num))
            num = num + 1
    
    for i in palindrome_special():
        print(i)
```

Comment: This answer is rather misleading. `StopIteration` is still raised when the generator finishes. It's just that the for statement `for i in palindrome_special();` hides this by catching `StopIteration` internally.